# Error when using pycotem to index an electron diffraction pattern?

Tags: python, software-assistance, diffraction, graphical-user-interface, pycotem

In the [pycotem code](https://github.com/mompiou/pycotem), this error comes up when using the Diffraction GUI.

```
pycotem\diffraction_main_.py", line 186, in angle_check
inc = ui.ListBox_d_2.currentItem().text().split(',')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Has anyone tried to resolve this?

Comment: Did you do something specific in the GUI before this error triggered or was it immediately when the program opened? If you gave some input or entered some command, we will need to know what those were. If it was immediate, you may have not installed a required dependency or else it may be an error with the program itself, for which you should submit an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you may have already posted an issue on GitHub. Is this also your account: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/3680/anya? If so, you can get the two merged by following [this link](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to contact the community managers.

Answer (score 1):

The [corresponding issue](https://github.com/mompiou/pycotem/issues/4) for this was closed on Github. According to the package author, mompiou:

> It seems to me that the error comes from the fact that you forgot to select a measurement in the `Dist, Incl` box before adding the data. Please refer to the [documentation](https://mompiou.github.io/pycotem/diffraction/#workflow).